# How to run go server on docker from binary

Tags: docker, go, binary

I have been trying to make a Dockerfile, that would let me build my go server as binary and then run it either from the scratch image or alpine. The server works fine locally, on macOS 10.13.5, and I made it work when it wasn't from binary on Docker.

I keep getting this error:

> standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "exec format error"

I have been googling around and found something about system architecture. I am not sure how to check if that is the error and/or how to fix it.

Any hints for debugging or possible fix are much appreciated.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.10.3 as builder
WORKDIR /go/src/gitlab.com/main/server
COPY . .
RUN go get -d -v ./...
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -o main .

FROM scratch
ADD main /
CMD ["/main"]
```

The output:

```
Building go
Step 1/9 : FROM golang:1.10.3 as builder
 ---> 4e611157870f
Step 2/9 : WORKDIR /go/src/gitlab.com/main/server
Removing intermediate container 20cd4d66008b
 ---> 621d9fc02dde
Step 3/9 : COPY . .
 ---> cab639571baf
Step 4/9 : RUN go get -d -v ./...
 ---> Running in 7681f9adc7b2
Removing intermediate container 7681f9adc7b2
 ---> 767a4c9dfb94
Step 5/9 : RUN go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o main .
 ---> Running in a6ec73121163
Removing intermediate container a6ec73121163
 ---> b9d7d1c0d2f9
Step 6/9 : FROM alpine:latest
 ---> 11cd0b38bc3c
Step 7/9 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6d321d334b8f
Step 8/9 : COPY . .
 ---> 048a59fcdd8f
Step 9/9 : CMD ["/app/main"]
 ---> Running in d50d174644ff
Removing intermediate container d50d174644ff
 ---> 68f8f3c6cdf7
Successfully built 68f8f3c6cdf7
Successfully tagged main_go:latest
Creating go ... done
Attaching to go
go           | standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "exec format error"
go exited with code 1
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds). But I don't see the `COPY --from=builder` line which is supposed to copy the built artifact from the previous stage into the new stage. Have you checked if this is the problem?

Comment: You log shown to us seems not come from the dockerfile you attached.

Comment: as suggested by @tgogos just comment out the `ADD main /`  and add `COPY --from=builder  /go/src/gitlab.com/main/server/main . ` then it will build and execute fine ... at least it does at my end

Comment: @atline yeah sorry about that tried a bunch of different things and forgot to correct both, but I got the error all the places :)
Thank you @tgogos! Apparently, it was the only thing missing and now it is working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @tgogos pointed out did I need to use what I build in the first step.

My final Dockerfile ended like this with a few further improvements: The important part is second last line though:

```
FROM golang:1.10.3 AS build
WORKDIR /go/src/gitlab.com/main/server
COPY . .
RUN go get github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep && \
      dep ensure && \
      rm -f schema/bindata.go && \
      go generate ./schema
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -o main .

FROM alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache ca-certificates
COPY --from=build /go/src/gitlab.com/main/server/main .
CMD ["/main"]
```